# using outer() to replace nested for in R

Tags: r, outer-join

I have a simple R code to add up the components of a 2x2 matrix

```
sum<-0
for(i in 1:2){ # row
    for(j in 1:2){ #column
      sum<-sum+mat[i,j]
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to use the outer(), or any other function to replace this piece of code and make it more efficient? My aim is to replace nested for loops in my entire code to bring down the time needed to execute my program.

Edit:
I also want to try using it on code snippets like:

```
for(i in 1:2){ # row
    for(j in 1:2){ #coloumn

      chisqr<- chisqr+ ((mat[i,j]-expmat[i,j])^2)/expmat[i,j]

    }
  }
```

and:

```
  for(i in 1:2){ # row
    for(j in 1:2){ #coloumn
      rowsum<-0
      colsum<-0

      for(k in 1:2){
        rowsum<- rowsum+mat[i,k]
      }

      for(k in 1:2){
        colsum<- colsum+mat[k,j]
      }

      expmat[i,j]<- (rowsum*colsum)/sum
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sum(mat)
```

will do the trick. There's no need for a loop or `outer`.

---

**Update based on new questions:**

You could calculate `expmat` using `outer`:

```
outer(rowSums(mat), colSums(mat))/sum(mat)
```

---

Afterwards, you could calculate `chisqr`:

```
sum((mat-expmat)^2/expmat)
```

*By the way*: I recommend having a look at `?chisq.test`.

Comment: I encountered another problem though, and I wanted to see if I can use outer there... In the code below,

for(i in 1:2){ # row
    for(j in 1:2){ #coloumn
      rowsum<-0
      colsum<-0
      
      for(k in 1:2){
        rowsum<- rowsum+mat[i,k]
      }
      
      for(k in 1:2){
        colsum<- colsum+mat[k,j]
      }
      
      expmat[i,j]<- (rowsum*colsum)/sum
    }
  }

and

for(i in 1:2){ # row
    for(j in 1:2){ #coloumn
      
      chisqr<- chisqr+ ((mat[i,j]-expmat[i,j])^2)/expmat[i,j]
      
    }
  }

I wanted to use a function to replace the nested for loops.

Comment: @user1847296 See the update of my answer. Generally, you should not extend your questions but post new questions.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Sven! Works like a charm!
And, will be mindful about the tip!